# Cannot find the Amazon E2C Image

Tags: relays, exit-relays, configuration, relay-adversary

cloud.torproject.org describes an image that can be used in Amazon E2C service. It mentions that this image is already configured with package updates and port forwarding.

> The images have been configured with automatic package updates and port forwarding, so you do not have to worry about Tor not working or the server not getting security updates. Get started with Tor Cloud

But I am not able to find this image nor download it from anywhere.

Where can this image be downloaded from?

Currently, I am using Ubuntu 14.01 LTS with Tor installed from Tor repositories and have the relay up and running. I would like to know better options.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the steps described on https://cloud.torproject.org/#get_started

The IDs of the images are `ami-4a7c1a23` for an obfsproxy bridge and `ami-567c1a3f` for a private bridge. You don't need to download them to install them in E2C.

Comment: I did a search for both names in the E2C but was unable to find them. If you were successful, do let me know. Could they have been removed?